# Bad parameter error when sending ping via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping

I'm trying to send pings to find out who is on my subnet, so i found this :

```
response = os.system("ping -c 1" +hostname)
```

but when it gets to this line it gives me an error:

```
bad parameter -c
```

I need to send ping and get as response 1 for no answer or 0 for an answer
any one can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing `"ping -c 1" +hostname` to  `"ping -c 1 " +hostname`. Im guessing is must be a space?

Comment: Are you on Windows? I don't see any `-c` option in ping's documentation.

Comment: i have windows, is there a different parameter for windows?

Comment: type `ping /?` and you will see windows params

Comment: Try changing `-c` to `-n`

Comment: the response stays the same even when sending the ping to an ip that is not on the network

Comment: Could you add the full error output to the question?

Comment: its not an error . it just doesnt work well.

Comment: i dont see any windows parameter that return treu or false if the ping got an answer

Comment: What is the output if you try to ping a IP that is ON the network?

Comment: When pinging to an ip that is on the network the output is :
repl from ip:bytes = 32 time<1ms TTL=128>
When pinging to an ip that is not on the nwetowrk the output is destination unreachable

Comment: the pinging works 
i need some way to know if the ip answered or not

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning **response** to the exit code of the function. 0 means successful, otherwise it is some error code not always 1. You would be better off just checking if `response != 0` that would mean it failed for some reason.  Also the response of `os.system` may differ on on OS https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system you might want to look into [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

On **Windows** replace **-c** with **-n**

```
>>> import os
>>> response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + "127.0.0.1")
>>> response
0
>>> response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + "abc")
>>> response
512
>>> response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + "12.0.0.1")
>>> response
256
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", "127.0.0.1"])
>>> response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", "127.0.0.1"])
>>> response
0
>>> response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", "abc"])
>>> response
2
>>> response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", "12.0.0.1"])
>>> response
1
```

Comment: tryied response !=0,
still doesnt work,
also subprocess.

Comment: I'm now trying to check if in in the response from :
subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-n", "1", hostname]) there is the word "unreachable"
but its now working  - i tried find and in methods